# how vim plugin youcompleteme add c++ vector push_back complete?

Tags: vim-plugin, youcompleteme

This is my .ycm_extra_conf.py and .vimrc configuration file.

[when i input vector variable, i can't now see the push_back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVQ6.png)

[are there any wrong configration in .vimrc?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcQat.png)

```html
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
-- Client logfile: /tmp/ycm_I6SEP7.log
-- Server Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python
-- Server Python version: 2.7.12
-- Server has Clang support compiled in: True
-- Clang version: clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
-- Extra configuration file found and loaded
-- Extra configuration path: /home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/y
cmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py
-- C-family completer debug information:
--   Compilation database path: None
--   Flags: ['-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-Wno-long-long', '-Wno-variadic-mac
ros', '-fexceptions', '-DNDEBUG', '-DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER', '-x', 'c++', '-std=c+
+11', '-isystem', '/home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/Bo
ostParts', '-isystem', '/usr/include/python2.7', '-isystem', '/home/casey/.vim/b
undle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/llvm/include', '-isystem', '/home/casey
/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/llvm/tools/clang/include', '-I',
 '/home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm', '-I', '/usr/i
nclude', '-I', '/usr/include/c++/5.4.0', '-I', '/usr/local/include', '-I', '/hom
e/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/ClangCompleter', '-is
ystem', '/home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gm
ock/gtest', '-isystem', '/home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/
cpp/ycm/tests/gmock/gtest/include', '-isystem', '/home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouComp
leteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock', '-isystem', '/home/casey/.vim/bund
le/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock/include', '-isystem', '/ho
me/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/benchmarks/benchmark
/include', '-std=c++11', '-resource-dir=/home/casey/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/th
ird_party/ycmd/ycmd/../clang_includes', '-fspell-checking']
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:60335
-- Server process ID: 22184
-- Server logfiles:
--   /tmp/ycmd_60335_stdout_7PnwKY.log
--   /tmp/ycmd_60335_stderr_qvyDYc.log
```

Comment: env:ubuntu1604 
install ycm: sudo ./install.py --clang-completer

Comment: Please add code as text and not as image.